# Conditional compile when running in Simulator as opposed to on a device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator, compiler-directives

Is there a compiler directive I can use to compile a different line of code when targetting the simulator as opposed to my device. Something like:

```
# IF SIMULATOR
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
# ELSE
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
# END
```

*EDIT*

[Direct link to docs.](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH19-SW3)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
#else
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
#endif
```

Comment: TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is deprecated. Prefer the TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR

Answer (score 11):

**Update: (Deprecated/Obsolete) This only worked for a few years, and does not work any more. (10+ years later)**

For the record, here's another method which Apple uses in some of their official Sample Code:

```
#if TARGET_CPU_ARM
  // Only executes on an iPhone or iPod touch device
  [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
#else
  // Only executes on the Simulator
  [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
#endif
```

Comment: In this case it seems like Apple's sample code is wrong, this code would break if they changed architectures for devices (or Macs).

Comment: This turned out to be a prescient comment.

Answer (score 6):

For those looking for a modern Swift solution, the (new) platform condition `targetEnvironment` provides the definitive answer here. For instance:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
#else
self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
#endif
```

The *target environment platform condition* feature was introduced by [SE-0190](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0190-target-environment-platform-condition.md) and is available since **Swift 4.1**.